# How do I change the size of the menu for the Atom editor?

Tags: ubuntu, menu, editor, atom-editor

The Atom editor on my system opened with a huge font yesterday and the menus are unusable. I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to reduce the size of the font in the text editor, but the font in the menu remains huge and unreadable.

[image: Screenshot of atom]

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and tried removing atom from apt-get (using --purge) and removed the ~/.atom/ directory where my configuration was stored.  After reinstalling Atom the font remains huge.

Atom seems to be the only application with this problem. All other applications have the menu at the top of the screen not in the window like Atom.  Could this be related?

Does anyone know how to fix the large menu in Atom?

Comment: This should probably be posted in Superuser

Answer (score 3):

Font Size for UI, go to Setting->Theme and then:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perfect solution. This had indeed solved my problem when I used Atom in my Cent OS. I remember not having any such things in Windows but for the linux build (.rpm), it appears to have been shipped with the lesser UI font size which is almost making it unusable! This has saved my life :)

Answer (score 0):

The large menu fonts seemed to be related to unity-tweak-tools.  I uninstalled unity-tweak-tools and the menus for Atom returned to the normal size.

It remains a mystery why the Atom editor was the only program with huge menus.  Other application menus were normal sized.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been unable to find an answer to this. It's a seemingly simple bug that makes it impossible to use.

Comment: This could me a comment, but shouldn't be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ether you using default or installed custom theme for atom, go to theme settings, font size can be set in there (I use one-dark-ui, atom version 1.24.0). 
After second look, sadly it applies for all menu, except for top line action menu (File Edit View etc.) sorry, I see that is the problem...

Comment: It answers half a question. I think you will need to modify this as well. Second part is Desktop environment Appearance Font settings. For Ubuntu 16.04 Xfce it applies for atom menu. I do not use Unity can not test it.

Answer (score 0):

You could delete the config/Atom folder as rough solution. Atom will create default settings next time it launches. Warning: Do create a backup before deleting settings